# import .py file from parent directory in flask project

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I meet an issue from the beginning of my flask project.

my project is like :

```
project/--
        |--run.py
        |--fbapp/-------
        |--config.py  |--views.py
                      |--_init_.py
                      |--template/---
```

ps:run.py, the folder fbapp/, and config.py is in the project/ folder

when I execute views.py, i got the error :

```
ImportError: No module named 'config'
```

It resolve when I move the config.py file in the fbapp/ directory, but
It will lead some probleme when I will use SQLAlchemy library.
I need to have config.py and run.py in the same directory.

views.py :

```
from flask import Flask 
app = Flask(__name__)

# Config options - Make sure you created a 'config.py' file.
app.config.from_object('config')
# To get one variable, tape app.config['MY_VARIABLE']
@app.route('/')

def index():
    return "Hello world !"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

config.py :

```
SECRET_KEY = 'some_secret_key'
FB_APP_ID = 000011112222333444
```

`__init__`.py :

```
from flask import Flask
from .views import app
```

thank you in advance

here the whole project :https://github.com/oc-courses/concevez_un_site_avec_flask/tree/P1C2

Comment: From what folder do you run the code? from `/project`?

Comment: I think you should always start flask by running run.py

Comment: Yes, I second that: from `project/`, run `python run.py` or something equivalent.

Comment: from fbapp, yeah for run the whole project, i should run run.py but for testing views.py, it should work.
because as i said , if it don't work , it bring some other error when I use the SQL alchemy library and add some data to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must add: `__init__.py` (empty) file to your package otherweise you cannot find the module:

```
project/--
     |--__init__.py #this tells python interpreter project is a python module
     |--fbapp/------
     |--run.py     |--template/---
     |--config.py  |--views.py
     |--__init__.py #this tells python interpreter fbapp is a python module
```

if you dont 'declare' a folder as python module, you cannot import from it

so in `views.py` you'll have to do :
`from fbapp.config import <what you need>`

PS: my suggestion, in python is to create 'modules' by IDE interface, so the IDE itself will bother with this.

Comment: Ok so I add an empty file (without any code) named __init__.py to the project folder and add **import config**  to views.py
Now i got  **ImportError :No module named 'config'**

Comment: you have to do from fbapp.config import <whay you need>

Comment: and there are a way to import everything from config.py ? because I will have to add more line in config.py

Comment: good reading about packages and imports: http://zetcode.com/lang/python/packages/

Comment: anyway: "direct answer" is: `from fbapp.config import *`

Comment: but `fbapp.config import` wouln't mean that config should be in the fbapp folder instead of project folder

Comment: From the schema I thaught fbapp contained  run and config... if your config is in "project" folder, than add `__init__.py` to project and your import will be `from project.config import *`